# Why does OR logic in the filter makes the cypher query run faster?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an interesting question regarding cypher in neo4j. When I use a filter (WHERE) in the query without "OR" logic, then it takes longer than using a filter using with "OR" logic.

For example:
The query below gives patients who were admitted to the hospital from 2010 until the end of 2012 
through emergency department diagnosed with RSV (primary diagnosis) and Asthma (secondary diagnosis).

**1-**

```
MATCH  (d:Diagnosis)-[r2:SC_EXISTS_IN]->(e:Encounter)<-[r3:PATIENT_HAS]-(p:Person)
WHERE (d.DIAG='49300_diag' OR 
d.DIAG='49301_diag' OR d.DIAG='49302_diag' OR d.DIAG='49310_diag' OR d.DIAG='49311_diag' OR d.DIAG='49312_diag' OR  
d.DIAG='49320_diag' OR d.DIAG='49321_diag' OR d.DIAG='49322_diag' OR d.DIAG='49381_diag' OR d.DIAG='49382_diag' OR 
d.DIAG='49390_diag' OR d.DIAG='49391_diag' OR d.DIAG='49392_diag') AND 
( e.ADMIT_YEAR='2012' or e.ADMIT_YEAR='2011' or e.ADMIT_YEAR='2010' ) 
WITH e,p
MATCH (d2:Diagnosis)-[r5:PR_EXISTS_IN]->(e)-[VISIT_TYPE_IS]->(t:Type)
WHERE (t.TYPE='1_outptype') AND d2.DIAG='0796_diag'
RETURN count(distinct p), count(distinct e);
```

**2-**

```
MATCH  (d:Diagnosis)-[r2:SC_EXISTS_IN]->(e:Encounter)<-[r3:PATIENT_HAS]-(p:Person)
WHERE (d.DIAG='49300_diag' OR 
d.DIAG='49301_diag' OR d.DIAG='49302_diag' OR d.DIAG='49310_diag' OR d.DIAG='49311_diag' OR d.DIAG='49312_diag' OR  
d.DIAG='49320_diag' OR d.DIAG='49321_diag' OR d.DIAG='49322_diag' OR d.DIAG='49381_diag' OR d.DIAG='49382_diag' OR 
d.DIAG='49390_diag' OR d.DIAG='49391_diag' OR d.DIAG='49392_diag') AND 
( e.ADMIT_YEAR='2012' or e.ADMIT_YEAR='2011' or e.ADMIT_YEAR='2010' ) 
WITH e,p
MATCH (d2:Diagnosis)-[r5:PR_EXISTS_IN]->(e)-[VISIT_TYPE_IS]->(t:Type)
WHERE (t.TYPE='1_outptype' OR t.TYPE='1_outptype') AND d2.DIAG='0796_diag'
RETURN count(distinct p), count(distinct e);
```

The only difference between them is putting an additional OR logic (t.TYPE='1_outptype') in the query. At this point, the 1st query performs in about 5 seconds whereas the 2nd one performs about 0.1 seconds. I tried with other queries and having an "OR" logic mostly make the query run faster.

Why is that in neo4j?

Comment: You can compare the query plans by adding `PROFILE` to the beginning of each query.

Comment: Goodness, use `d.DIAG IN ['49300_diag', '49301_diag', '49302_diag', etc...]`!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're seeing is cold caches vs. warm caches.
If you run both queries in reverse order you should see the opposite.

Otherwise run your queries with PROFILE prefixed and share the output.

And use Brian's suggestion to use

1. parameters
2. t.DIAG IN {diags}
3. same for ADMIT_YEAR
4. and make sure there is a unique constraint for DIAG and an index for ADMIT_YEAR